# jsfiddle creation not transferring to website

Tags: jquery, jsfiddle

I modified a simple image slider in jsfiddle and can't figure out why I can't get it to work on my first clients website. Works fine in jsFiddle but not on the site.

It uses a couple other plugins for smooth scrolling (which I think I broke trying to transfer this over =/). This is one of my first 'clients' I took on to get my development portfolio going.

Here is a link to the jsFiddle code - http://jsfiddle.net/SbDpR/

JS snippet

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var height = 340,
        width = 740,
        slides = 5,
        contentNum = 1;
    $('.testing').html("Content Number - " + contentNum);
    $('.main_inner').css({
    width: slides * width
    });
    $('.next a').click(function(){
        if (contentNum < slides) {  
           $('.main_inner').animate({
            marginLeft: '-' + (width * contentNum)
            }, 600);
            contentNum = contentNum + 1;
            $('.testing').html("Content Number - " + contentNum);
        } else {
           $('.main_inner').animate({
            marginLeft: '0'
            }, 600);
            contentNum = contentNum / contentNum;
             $('.testing').html("Content Number - " + contentNum);
        }
        return false;
    });

    $('.previous a').click(function(){
        if (contentNum > 1) {
           $('.main_inner').animate({
            marginLeft: '+=740'
            }, 600);
            contentNum = contentNum - 1;
            $('.testing').html("Content Number - " + contentNum);
        } else {
            $('.main_inner').animate({
            marginLeft: '-2960'
            }, 600);
            contentNum = 5;
            $('.testing').html("Content Number - " + contentNum);
        }
        return false;
    });
});​
```

Here is a link to the site to see it in action - http://skeptikalmedia.com/MOM/index.html

I've spent the last 4 hours trying to get it to work on the live site. I've copied/pasted/deleted/copied/pasted. Currently the script sits on the index page to make sure I didn't miss importing a file or something.

Any ideas? I'm to the point where I'd almost pay for someone to tell me why it's not working or turn the JSFiddle into a jQuery plugin.

Comment: Everything on the website is placed absolute as the images and text needed to be placed along a scroll path (that kind of follows the tree branch) and I have a strange feeling that is causing issues here.

Comment: Have you checked the JavaScript console? Something like `SyntaxError: Invalid character '\u8203'` could be a problem.

Comment: You have a JS error, `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL `

Comment: Looks like you have a bit of copy'n'paste garbage right after the final `});` in your JavaScript.

Comment: Jsfiddle, causing headaches yet again with invisible characters.

Comment: I saw that error in the console and started deleting white space. Error is gone now but script still not working. Thanks for the heads up mu

Comment: is that plugin dependent on jquery-ui  ?  because that comes automatically in jsfiddle when you select jquery 1.8.2 ?

Comment: Wow thanks Scott! removing that plugin seemed to have fixed the smooth scrolling and the jquery buttons are moving the slides, unfortunately they're all still right on top of eachother though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class `.wrapper div` has `position: absolute;`.  Remove this, and everything looks as it is supposed to, either that, or alter your existing css as follows(`position: static` is the default positioning for html elements):

```
.main_inner > div {
    position: static;
}
```

Comment: As you have already figured out your other problems, I did not add them to this answer.  It doesn't seem right that I should get points for a solution that wasn't my own.

Comment: Kudos. Thank you so much. I'm just curious so I understand, but adding the 'position:absolute' to the '.wrapper div' actually by default gave every element within the '.wrapper div' that positioning?

Comment: @Brandon Yep, that's what happened, and that's what it usually means.  If you wish to select a specific div in the hierarchy, use the `>` symbol to point to that div, but note while doing this that you have to traverse the tree, so if the div you want is behind a `ul`, it becomes `.wrapper > ul > div`, or etc.

Answer (score 0):

change this code

```
<div id="content1" class="content">
```

to

```
<div id="content1" class="content" style="position: relative;">
```

same for your other content2 , content3 ....